# How to convert thread Code (VB.net to C#)..?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

how to convert my VB.net code to C#..?
I want to use a looping function with a thread.

1. VB.Net Code

   ```
       For i As Integer = 0 To _port_count
           Dim worker As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf looping)
           worker.Start(_list(i))
           commThread.Add(worker)
       Next
   ```

public sub looping(Byvar PortList As PortList) 'looping function

2. C# Code

   ```
         for (int i = 0; i <= _port_count; i++)
           {
               Thread worker = new Thread(looping);
               worker.Start(_list[i]);
               commThread.Add(worker);
           }
   ```

public static void looping (PortList PortList) {}

but C# code didn't work. :(

thanks for your helps.

Comment: *"code didn't work"* is never an adequate description. You need to describe exactly what did happen and how that differed from your expectations. That almost certainly means debugging the code to see exactly what gets executed and what data it used.

Comment: first i got CS1503 Error.. Thread worker = new Thread(looping) i guess looping is the problem.

Comment: What was the actual error message? We shouldn't have to drag every little bit of information out of you. My guess is that the method signature is incompatible, because a `ThreadStart` delegate has a parameter of type `object`. I shouldn't have to guess though. You have this diagnostic information right in front of you.

Comment: error message is 1 argument: can not convert from 'method group' to 'ThreadStart'. if you can't understand i'm so sorry my english is not good.

Comment: @IlwooShin - It's not your English - it's the lack of information that you've given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Thread` constructor will take either a `ThreadStart` delegate or a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate. The first has no parameters and the second has one parameter of type `object`. If you're using a named method then it has to match one of those two signatures, which yours does not.  VB will allow you to do the wrong thing and attempt to clean up for you if it can but C# expects you to do the right thing yourself.  These days, if you want to call a method whose signature does not match, you can use a Lambda with a matching signature instead, then call your method in that:

```
Thread worker = new Thread(() => looping(_list[i]));
worker.Start();
```

Comment: wow.. finally i resolved!!! really thank you very much.
and thank you all for your helps. :) have a good day

Comment: well.. i'm using Visual Studio 2017. when i dubuged with F8 it worked well but F5 is not working. i got System.IndexOutOfRangeException :( How can i fix it?

Comment: And where are you getting the index from? The loop counter. So fix your loop.

Comment: If you have a list with 10 items then the count will be 10. How, then, could indexes from 0 to 10 be valid?

Answer (score 0):

What's declaration of looping function ?

And some more info ?

Here is an example from Microsoft Docs.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Work
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized static method.
        Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
        newThread.Start(42);

        // Start a thread that calls a parameterized instance method.
        Work w = new Work();
        newThread = new Thread(w.DoMoreWork);
        newThread.Start("The answer.");
    }

    public static void DoWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure. Data='{0}'",
            data);
    }

    public void DoMoreWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data='{0}'",
            data);
    }
}
// This example displays output like the following:
//       Static thread procedure. Data='42'
//       Instance thread procedure. Data='The answer.'
```

link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459(v=vs.110)

Comment: yes.. i still have a problem.  Thread worker = new Thread(looping);  i got an error CS1503 with looping.

Answer (score 0):

Change you looping-method signature to following:

```
public static void looping (object PortList)
```

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=netframework-4.7.2) says, `ParameterizedThreadStart` passed as Thread constructor parameter has to be `object`.